# Does mongodb compensate for Date constructor's 0-based index?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following code. Why `month` gets incremented by 1?

```
> var myDate = new Date(2016,01,01);
> db.testDate.insert({"aDate": myDate});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.testDate.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e2a5a46d5f3aabab82c08d"), "aDate" : ISODate("2016-02-01T05:00:00Z") }
> var myDate = new Date(2016,00,01);
> db.testDate.insert({"aDate": myDate});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.testDate.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e2a5a46d5f3aabab82c08d"), "aDate" : ISODate("2016-02-01T05:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e2ab016d5f3aabab82c08e"), "aDate" : ISODate("2016-01-01T05:00:00Z") }
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(2016,01,01);` creates Date object using the ISODate wrapper. This accepts date in current timezone and the ISODate wrapper converts it to the UTC time.

Also, range of month is 0-11. 0 is January and 11 is December. So to store January 1st, 2016, the declaration must be `var myDate = new Date(2016,0,1);`

You can also create Date object using the `ISODate()` constructor.

```
> var myDate = new ISODate("2016-01-01");
> myDate
ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z")
> var myDate = new ISODate();
> myDate
ISODate("2016-09-21T16:24:32.153Z")
```